# Groovy, create map out of array

Tags: java, groovy

I have an array of elements and wanted to create a map out of it

```
def vegetable = ['carrot', 'salad']
def fruit = ['orange', 'apple']
def all_food = group_a + group_b

def my_map = [:]
for(item in all_food) {
    my_map.put(item, "edible")
}
```

any thought how to create it inline?

```
def my_map = all_food.each{it, "edible"}
```

or smth similar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
def result = all_food.collectEntries {[it, "edible"]}
```

Comment: you can also return a tuple to collectEntries, which makes it a bit
easier to comprehend: `[it, 'editable']`.